# Keras - Save image embedding of the mnist data set

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, tensorboard, mnist

I've written the following simple MLP network for the `MNIST` db.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras import callbacks


batch_size = 100
num_classes = 10
epochs = 20

tb = callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='/Users/shlomi.shwartz/tensorflow/notebooks/logs/minist', histogram_freq=10, batch_size=32,
                           write_graph=True, write_grads=True, write_images=True,
                           embeddings_freq=10, embeddings_layer_names=None,
                           embeddings_metadata=None)

early_stop = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0,
                     patience=3, verbose=1, mode='auto')


# the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784)
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(60, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    callbacks=[tb,early_stop],
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

The model ran fine, and I could see the scalars info on TensorBoard. However when I've changed **embeddings_freq=10** to try and visualize the images (Like [seen here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/embedding_viz)) I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shlomi.shwartz/IdeaProjects/TF/src/minist.py", line 65, in <module>
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
  File "/Users/shlomi.shwartz/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 870, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/Users/shlomi.shwartz/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1507, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/Users/shlomi.shwartz/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1117, in _fit_loop
    callbacks.set_model(callback_model)
  File "/Users/shlomi.shwartz/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 52, in set_model
    callback.set_model(model)
  File "/Users/shlomi.shwartz/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 719, in set_model
    self.saver = tf.train.Saver(list(embeddings.values()))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1139, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1161, in build
    raise ValueError("No variables to save")
ValueError: No variables to save
```

**Q:** What am I missing? is that the right way of doing it in Keras?

**Update:** I understand there is some prerequisite in order to use embedding projection, however I haven't found a good tutorial for doing so in Keras, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what was the value of `embeddings_freq` before you changed it to 10 and got the error?

Comment: The value was zero

Comment: Can you please clarify Keras & Tensorflow versions, and confirm that you use Python 3.6.1?

Comment: keras 2.0 TF 1.2 Python 3.6.1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What is called "embedding" here in `callbacks.TensorBoard` is, in a broad sense, any layer weight. According to [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard):

> embeddings_layer_names: a list of names of layers to keep eye on. If None or empty list all the embedding layer will be watched.

So *by default*, it's going to monitor the `Embedding` layers, but you don't really need a `Embedding` layer to use this visualization tool.

In your provided MLP example, what's missing is the `embeddings_layer_names` argument. You have to figure out which layers you're going to visualize. Suppose you want to visualize the weights (or, `kernel` in Keras) of all `Dense` layers, you can specify `embeddings_layer_names` like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(60, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

embedding_layer_names = set(layer.name
                            for layer in model.layers
                            if layer.name.startswith('dense_'))

tb = callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='temp', histogram_freq=10, batch_size=32,
                           write_graph=True, write_grads=True, write_images=True,
                           embeddings_freq=10, embeddings_metadata=None,
                           embeddings_layer_names=embedding_layer_names)

model.compile(...)
model.fit(...)
```

Then, you can see something like this in TensorBoard:
[image: tensorboard]

You can see [the relevant lines in Keras source](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L707-L718) if you want to figure out what's happening regarding `embeddings_layer_names`.

---

### Edit:

So here's a dirty solution for visualizing layer outputs. Since the original `TensorBoard` callback does not support this, implementing a new callback seems inevitable.

Since it will take up a lot of page space to re-write the entire `TensorBoard` callback here, I'll just extend the original `TensorBoard`, and write out the parts that are different (which is already quite lengthy). But to avoid duplicated computations and model saving, re-writing the `TensorBoard` callback will be a better and cleaner way.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Model
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

class TensorResponseBoard(TensorBoard):
    def __init__(self, val_size, img_path, img_size, **kwargs):
        super(TensorResponseBoard, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.val_size = val_size
        self.img_path = img_path
        self.img_size = img_size

    def set_model(self, model):
        super(TensorResponseBoard, self).set_model(model)

        if self.embeddings_freq and self.embeddings_layer_names:
            embeddings = {}
            for layer_name in self.embeddings_layer_names:
                # initialize tensors which will later be used in `on_epoch_end()` to
                # store the response values by feeding the val data through the model
                layer = self.model.get_layer(layer_name)
                output_dim = layer.output.shape[-1]
                response_tensor = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([self.val_size, output_dim]),
                                              name=layer_name + '_response')
                embeddings[layer_name] = response_tensor

            self.embeddings = embeddings
            self.saver = tf.train.Saver(list(self.embeddings.values()))

            response_outputs = [self.model.get_layer(layer_name).output
                                for layer_name in self.embeddings_layer_names]
            self.response_model = Model(self.model.inputs, response_outputs)

            config = projector.ProjectorConfig()
            embeddings_metadata = {layer_name: self.embeddings_metadata
                                   for layer_name in embeddings.keys()}

            for layer_name, response_tensor in self.embeddings.items():
                embedding = config.embeddings.add()
                embedding.tensor_name = response_tensor.name

                # for coloring points by labels
                embedding.metadata_path = embeddings_metadata[layer_name]

                # for attaching images to the points
                embedding.sprite.image_path = self.img_path
                embedding.sprite.single_image_dim.extend(self.img_size)

            projector.visualize_embeddings(self.writer, config)

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        super(TensorResponseBoard, self).on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)

        if self.embeddings_freq and self.embeddings_ckpt_path:
            if epoch % self.embeddings_freq == 0:
                # feeding the validation data through the model
                val_data = self.validation_data[0]
                response_values = self.response_model.predict(val_data)
                if len(self.embeddings_layer_names) == 1:
                    response_values = [response_values]

                # record the response at each layers we're monitoring
                response_tensors = []
                for layer_name in self.embeddings_layer_names:
                    response_tensors.append(self.embeddings[layer_name])
                K.batch_set_value(list(zip(response_tensors, response_values)))

                # finally, save all tensors holding the layer responses
                self.saver.save(self.sess, self.embeddings_ckpt_path, epoch)
```

To use it:

```
tb = TensorResponseBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=10, batch_size=10,
                         write_graph=True, write_grads=True, write_images=True,
                         embeddings_freq=10,
                         embeddings_layer_names=['dense_1'],
                         embeddings_metadata='metadata.tsv',
                         val_size=len(x_test), img_path='images.jpg', img_size=[28, 28])
```

Before launching TensorBoard, you'll need to save the labels and images to `log_dir` for visualization:

```
from PIL import Image
img_array = x_test.reshape(100, 100, 28, 28)
img_array_flat = np.concatenate([np.concatenate([x for x in row], axis=1) for row in img_array])
img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(255 * (1. - img_array_flat)))
img.save(os.path.join(log_dir, 'images.jpg'))
np.savetxt(os.path.join(log_dir, 'metadata.tsv'), np.where(y_test)[1], fmt='%d')
```

Here's the result:

[image: TensorResponseBoard]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what I really want is to display the images so I can see if the model group them together. What should I change in your answer so I can see the images?

Comment: So what you're trying to visualize is really not any layer weights of the model, but the *response* (or *prediction*) by feeding the images through the model. I don't think this is currently implemented in any Keras callback. Under current Keras framework, callbacks are only provided the `model` and `logs` (i.e. losses and metrics), but not the response at any layer.

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide a workaround. Please see if that's what you want.

Comment: I am unable to replicate this example. I am using  1.7.0 tensorflow and 2.1.5 keras. What were the versions used here?

Comment: @user42361 I have tried the same code on 1.7.0 tensorflow and 2.1.5 keras and there's no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need at least one Embedding Layer in Keras. On stats was a good explanation about them. It is not directly for Keras, but the concepts are roughly the same. [What is an embedding layer in a neural network](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182775/what-is-an-embedding-layer-in-a-neural-network)

Comment: Look at Yu-Yang comment. He has a way to use the tensorflow embedding visualization, without using embedding layers.

Comment: Yes, However using this approach I only see points in space, I want to link those points to the actual figure

Answer (score 1):

So, I conclude that what you actually want (it's not completely clear from your post) is to visualize the **predictions** of your model, in a manner similar to [this Tensorboard demo](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/embedding_viz).

To start with, reproducing this stuff is non-trivial [even in Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6322), let alone Keras. The said demo makes very brief and passing references to things like [metadata & sprite images](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/embedding_viz#metadata) that are necessary in order to obtain such visualizations.

Bottom line: although non-trivial, it is indeed possible to do it with Keras. You don't need the Keras callbacks; all you need is your model predictions, the necessary metadata & sprite image, and some pure TensorFlow code. So,

**Step 1** - get your model predictions for the test set:

```
emb = model.predict(x_test) # 'emb' for embedding
```

**Step 2a** - build a metadata file with the real labels of the test set:

```
import numpy as np

LOG_DIR = '/home/herc/SO/tmp'  # FULL PATH HERE!!!

metadata_file = os.path.join(LOG_DIR, 'metadata.tsv')
with open(metadata_file, 'w') as f:
    for i in range(len(y_test)):
        c = np.nonzero(y_test[i])[0][0]
        f.write('{}\n'.format(c))
```

**Step 2b** - get the sprite image `mnist_10k_sprite.png` as provided by the TensorFlow guys [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/images/mnist_10k_sprite.png), and place it in your `LOG_DIR`

**Step 3** - write some Tensorflow code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector

embedding_var = tf.Variable(emb,  name='final_layer_embedding')
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(embedding_var.initializer)
summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOG_DIR)
config = projector.ProjectorConfig()
embedding = config.embeddings.add()
embedding.tensor_name = embedding_var.name

# Specify the metadata file:
embedding.metadata_path = os.path.join(LOG_DIR, 'metadata.tsv')

# Specify the sprite image: 
embedding.sprite.image_path = os.path.join(LOG_DIR, 'mnist_10k_sprite.png')
embedding.sprite.single_image_dim.extend([28, 28]) # image size = 28x28

projector.visualize_embeddings(summary_writer, config)
saver = tf.train.Saver([embedding_var])
saver.save(sess, os.path.join(LOG_DIR, 'model2.ckpt'), 1)
```

Then, running Tensorboard in your `LOG_DIR`, and selecting color by label, here is what you get:

[image]

Modifying this in order to get predictions for other layers is straightforward, although in this case the Keras Functional API may be a better choice.