# Transpose tensorboard embedding projections

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

My model is trying to predict scores for 163 items using variety of inputs. It uses keras on tensorflow backend.
Following the approach in [Keras - Save image embedding of the mnist data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45265436/keras-save-image-embedding-of-the-mnist-data-set) to capture layer weights, I am capturing embedding data for final layer which is Dense(163). Since final dense layer is getting 128 inputs, weights matrix is 128x163. In Tensorboard Projector, I can see it visualizes 128 points very well. 
However when I try to map it to my real world items using meta data, I have 163 items names but Tensorboard Projecter is visualizing 128x163 weight matrix by dimension 0 i.e. 128 points. Is there any way to make it visualize points by dimension 1 (163 points) in Tensorboard Projector?